# Problem in updating the table with livewire

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a table that displays the price of digital currencies using Laravel that receives from an external web service
Now here's the problem, I want to update the table without refreshing the entire page using Livewire, I do this, but it doesn't work!

livewire blade :

```
<div wire:poll>
    <table class="currency">
        <thead class="thead">
        <tr>
            <x-dashboard.table.th name=""/>
            <x-dashboard.table.th name="token"/>
            <x-dashboard.table.th name="symbol"/>
            <x-dashboard.table.th name="price"/>
            <x-dashboard.table.th name="24h"/>
            <x-dashboard.table.th name="market"/>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="table_child">
        <tr>
            <x-dashboard.table.td name="{{__('custom.dashboard.main.table.td.coin', ['Name' => 'bitcoin'])}}"
                                  icon="bitcoin.png"
                                  symbol="{{__('custom.dashboard.main.symbol.symbol', ['Name' => 'BTC'])}}"
                                  price="${{number_format($data['data']['BTC']['USD']['price'])}}"
                                  status="{{$data['data']['BTC']['USD']['day']}}"
                                  statusIcon="{{$message = (substr($data['data']['BTC']['USD']['day'], 0, 1) === '-') ? 'down' :'up'}}"
                                  market="${{number_format($data['data']['BTC']['USD']['cap'])}}"/>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Livewire Php component :

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Currency;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Livewire\Component;

class Price extends Component
{

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.currency.price');
    }
}
```

I tried many ways, but unfortunately it didn't work!
The problem is not that it receives from an external service or that it receives the information without using Livewire and then updates Livewire?

I want to update using wire:poll, but it can't be done!
Please guide me *_*

I want to update using wire:poll, but it can't be done!
Please guide me *_*